# How to perform GroupBy in EF Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, ef-core-2.2, ef-core-3.0, ef-core-3.1

We have upgraded our application to Core 3.1, coming from 2.1. The following query no longer works.
What would be the best way to re-write it?

```
    public async Task<Dictionary<int, CoStatusUpdate>> GetDailyStatusUpdates(int organisationTypeId)
    {
        var dailyUpdates = await _context.CoStatusUpdates
            .Include(x => x.CoStatus)
            .Include(x => x.Company).ThenInclude(x => x.Organisation)
            .GroupBy(p => p.CompanyId)
                .Select(x => new CoStatusUpdate
                {
                    CompanyId = x.Key,
                    Company = new Company() //building new object for the only fields we need otherwise there's way more returned than needed
                    {
                        Organisation = new Organisation()
                        {
                            Name = x.FirstOrDefault(y => y.SubmittedDateTime == x.Max(z => z.SubmittedDateTime)).Company.Organisation.Name,
                            IsDeleted = x.FirstOrDefault(y => y.SubmittedDateTime == x.Max(z => z.SubmittedDateTime)).Company.Organisation.IsDeleted,
                            OrganisationTypeId = x.FirstOrDefault(y => y.SubmittedDateTime == x.Max(z => z.SubmittedDateTime)).Company.Organisation.OrganisationTypeId,
                        }
                    },
                    CoStatusUpdateId = x.FirstOrDefault(y => y.SubmittedDateTime == x.Max(z => z.SubmittedDateTime)).CoStatusUpdateId,
                    CoStatusId = x.FirstOrDefault(y => y.SubmittedDateTime == x.Max(z => z.SubmittedDateTime)).CoStatusId,
                    CoStatus = x.FirstOrDefault(y => y.SubmittedDateTime == x.Max(z => z.SubmittedDateTime)).CoStatus,
                    SubmittedDateTime = x.Max(z => z.SubmittedDateTime)
                }).Where(x => !x.Company.Organisation.IsDeleted
                     && x.Company.Organisation.OrganisationTypeId == organisationTypeId))
            .ToDictionaryAsync(x => x.CompanyId);

        return dailyUpdates;
    }
```

The error is:

> {"The LINQ expression '(GroupByShaperExpression:\r\nKeySelector: (f.CompanyId), \r\nElementSelector:(EntityShaperExpression: \r\n    EntityType: CoStatusUpdate\r\n    ValueBufferExpression: \r\n        (ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember)\r\n    IsNullable: False\r\n)\r\n)\r\n    .FirstOrDefault(y => y.SubmittedDateTime == (GroupByShaperExpression:\r\n    KeySelector: (f.CompanyId), \r\n    ElementSelector:(EntityShaperExpression: \r\n        EntityType: CoStatusUpdate\r\n        ValueBufferExpression: \r\n            (ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember)\r\n        IsNullable: False\r\n    )\r\n    )\r\n        .Max(z => z.SubmittedDateTime))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information."}

EDIT:

**The Solution For My Scenario**

Whilst I have accepted the first answer given (it provided the equivalent to what this query was already doing in Core 2.1) I have now found a way to actually perform the grouping server-side which is a lot more performant.

```
        var coUpdates = await _context.Companys
            .Where(p=>!p.Organisation.IsDeleted)  
            .Select(p => p.CompanyId)
          //.Distinct() //if you wouldn't already be getting a unique list of id's
            .Select(id => _context.coStatusUpdates
                .Include(u=>u.coStatus)
                .Include(u=>u.Company).ThenInclude(x=>x.Organisation)
                .OrderByDescending(p => p.SubmittedDateTime)  
                .FirstOrDefault(p => p.CompanyId == id))  
            .ToListAsync();

        var coUpdatesDictionary = coUpdates
            .Where(x => x != null)
            .ToDictionary(x=>x.CompanyId);

        return coUpdatesDictionary;
```

Comment: GroupBy works. It's the query itself that's causing trouble. EF can't translate *every* C# expression into SQL. If something can't be expressed as a SQL query, EF won't be able to generate that query either. What are you trying to do whith this query?

Comment: BTW the bug was already there. EF Core 1.x was incomplete though, so the EF team made the decision to silently pull all data to the client and process it there if it couldn't generate the proper SQL queries. Back in the 1.x days, even GroupBy was missing. In EF Core 2.x, client-side evaluation would log runtime warnings already.

Comment: WHat are you trying to do with that code? ORMs aren't meant for reporting queries, which is exactly what this is. If you want to return the latest status records for each company in a group, you can probably writhe a *single* SQL query using functions like [LAST_VALUE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/last-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to return the last StatusID by SubmittedDateTime. There's no way to use such functions in EF or EF Core though

Comment: Your query started failing due to the [#1 breaking change from EF Core 2.2 to 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#linq-queries-are-no-longer-evaluated-on-the-client). Olegl's answer is generally correct, but you might also want to look at your query more closely to see if there is any other way to optimize it. More specifically, by far not all the LINQ's `GroupBy` clauses can be translated into SQL's `GROUP BY` - try to rewrite your query to the simplest possible one.

Comment: @SergeyKudriavtsev I managed to get there in the end. Please see the update to my question which provides a solution for doing the grouping server side.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos There is a good solution in my question showing how to perform this server side. I would appreciate if you could upvote the question - someone has downvoted it for some reason which may put someone off reading it when it is actually informative and the method of rewriting could help others trying to re-write GroupBy's in Core 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to split this into two different queries:

```
var dailyUpdates = await _context.CoStatusUpdates
            .Include(x => x.CoStatus)
            .Include(x => x.Company)
               .ThenInclude(x => x.Organisation)
            .Where(x => !x.Company.Organisation.IsDeleted
                     && x.Company.Organisation.OrganisationTypeId == organisationTypeId))
            .ToListAsync();

var result = dailyUpdates.GroupBy(p => p.CompanyId)
                .Select(x => new CoStatusUpdate
                {
                    CompanyId = x.Key,
                    Company = new Company() //building new object for the only fields we need otherwise there's way more returned than needed
                    {
                        Organisation = new Organisation()
                        {
                            Name = x.FirstOrDefault(y => y.SubmittedDateTime == x.Max(z => z.SubmittedDateTime)).Company.Organisation.Name,
                            IsDeleted = x.FirstOrDefault(y => y.SubmittedDateTime == x.Max(z => z.SubmittedDateTime)).Company.Organisation.IsDeleted,
                            OrganisationTypeId = x.FirstOrDefault(y => y.SubmittedDateTime == x.Max(z => z.SubmittedDateTime)).Company.Organisation.OrganisationTypeId,
                        }
                    },
                    CoStatusUpdateId = x.FirstOrDefault(y => y.SubmittedDateTime == x.Max(z => z.SubmittedDateTime)).CoStatusUpdateId,
                    CoStatusId = x.FirstOrDefault(y => y.SubmittedDateTime == x.Max(z => z.SubmittedDateTime)).CoStatusId,
                    CoStatus = x.FirstOrDefault(y => y.SubmittedDateTime == x.Max(z => z.SubmittedDateTime)).CoStatus,
                    SubmittedDateTime = x.Max(z => z.SubmittedDateTime)
                })
            .ToDictionary(x => x.CompanyId);
```

Comment: This will cover up the error by loading *everything* in memory. The `Where` clause appies to the "outer" query though and could be applied to the first query to return just the matching companies.

Comment: Quite the opposite - the server will have to scan the entire table and join with all related tables before returning everything. Even when *most* of those records are useless. Then the client will have to filter out those useless records without benefit of indexing. You can just put the `Where` before `ToListAsync()` and only load the matching company statuses

Comment: Client-side evaluation is almost *always* slower than server-side. The client has no indexes, no idea what those records contain, no way to optimize joins, MAX/MIN calculations etc. It will have to loop over all that data over and over.

Comment: Thanks to all for the discussion and helpful points. This solution will do for our needs - performance is no worse, as essentially the grouping was happening client side before anyway. There is a finite number of companies (about 50) so I am tempted to run 50 queries and get the most recent entry per company. This could be more performant than bringing back 10000's of rows data before grouping.

Comment: @OlegI I have added a solution in my original question which I went with to make the group actually perform server side which runs a lot quicker in my scenario.